# Меры безопасности на web api сервисе

Tags: c#, безопасность, asp.net-web-api

Необходимо сделать небольшой web api сервис, служащий для сохранения отчётов, принятых с клиента (Android приложение). Отчёты присылаются в простой форме (POST-запросом): тело отчёта + опциональная информация. Необходимо обеспечить безопасность: максимально возможное количество отчётов в день около 500, потенциальный злоумышленник может отправить с одного ip-адреса достаточно большое количество запросов, нужно как-нибудь обработать такую ситуацию. Какие меры безопасности можно произвести?

1. Можно ли как-нибудь эффективно настроить CORS
2. Имеет ли смысл сделать какой-нибудь black list для ip-адресов, в
   который будут попадать все ip-адреса, отправившие больше, к примеру,
   10 запросов. Если у злоумышленника динамический ip-адрес, то тогда
   следует ограничить общее возможное количество запросов за день, но
   это тоже не вариант.

Есть ли какие-нибудь варианты решить даннную проблему?

Comment: приложение может пройти аутентификацию на стороне сервиса ? т.е. есть возможность изменять само приложение на Android ?

Comment: для веб апи обычно используют апи ключ, который нужно слать в каждом запросе. Вы можете задать просто лимит, создать словарь, куда складировать посещения, если разница между последними двумя маленькая, тогда игнорите запрос(подходит редис например).

Comment: @morphey83 смысл как раз таки не использовать подобные вещи и сделать простую реализацию отправки отчётов

Comment: @pashagoroshko складировать в словарь ip адрес и соответствующее ему время посещения?

Comment: @user190794 да, при этом старые и не нужные записи удалять, собственно, время жизни можно указать в редисе.

Comment: @user190794 но как я понял, для вас так же важен и пользователь? посмотрите в сторону api key, тогда каждый запрос будет localhost/api/home?id=12&Key=123

Comment: @pashagoroshko, если пользователь не будет авторизироваться, то как он получит апи-кей ? сам сгенерит ? приложение сгенерит по общему алгоритму, который может быть раскрыт ?

Comment: @morphey83, для получения ключа пользователю просто надо будет иметь свой аккаунт на данном сервисе. в идеале пользователь может даже создавать несколько ключей(которые будут привязаны к его учетке) и распределять нагрузку на каждый из ключей